# Create function and trigger in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have following database

- Customer (customerNO, customerName, address, city, category, custBalance)
- Product (productNO, label, price, QStock)
- CustomerOrder (orderNO, orderDate, #customerNO)
- OrderedProduct (#orderNO, #productNO , orderQuantity )

and want to create a trigger called changeCustomer_Category which should be invoked before any update of customer balance in customer table.

Its job is to modify the category of a customer from B2 to B1 and from C2 to C1 when a customer's balance status drops below a certain threshold (-10000).

I try this but it does not work

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER changeCustomer_Category
    AFTER update ON customer
    FOR EACH ROW
    ENABLE
    DECLARE 
     
   BEGIN

    
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd think of

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_au_cust
  2    before update on customer
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5     :new.category := case when :new.custbalance < -10000 then
  6                           case when :new.category = 'B2' then 'B1'
  7                                when :new.category = 'C2' then 'C1'
  8                           end
  9                           else :new.category
 10                      end;
 11  end trg_au_cust;
 12  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing: initial data:

```
SQL> select * from customer;

CA CUSTBALANCE
-- -----------
B2        5000
```

Shouldn't affect anything (as balance isn't lower than -10000):

```
SQL> update customer set custbalance = 100;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from customer;

CA CUSTBALANCE
-- -----------
B2         100
```

Setting really low balance:

```
SQL> update customer set custbalance = -20000;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from customer;

CA CUSTBALANCE
-- -----------
B1      -20000             --> right; category is now B1

SQL>
```